# QT creator: Комплекты. Что такое? Где взять?

Tags: qtcreator

Отсутствуют подходящие комплекты, где их взять?

Comment: что вы собираетесь сделать?

Comment: Какая у вес версия Qt Creator и операционная система?

Comment: Вы скорее всего недоставили креатор, убрали при установке галочки которые убирать не стоило. Переустановить проще всего.

Answer (score 1):

"Комплектом"  (Kit) Qt Creator называет набор из конфигурации Qt и компилятора.

Находятся комплекты в меню Tools->Options, раздел Build&Run, вкладка Kits.

Обычно, при установке QtCreator скачивается и ставится как минимум один комплект.